# Overall Average greater than Individual Category averages

Tags: mean, median

I am calculating Gender Pay gap using gross salaries for employees. I'm doing two things to be specific:

1. Calculate Overall Gender pay gap for all the employees. (Taking all male/female employees to calculate average salaries)
2. Calculate Gender Pay gap at each level/grade (Employees divided by Seniority)

I had a question about the numbers that I'm getting.

Q. **The Pay Gap for all individual grades is Negative (Women are paid more) except for one. (A total of 5 grades). But the overall Pay Gap I'm getting is quite Positive. Can anyone help explain what is happening here?**

Formula I'm using for Pay Gap: **(Avg_Male_monthly_gross - Avg_Female_monthly_gross) / Avg_Male_monthly_gross**

Thank you.

Comment: Without knowing your specific data, we likely can't say much. But my very first suspicion would be [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_paradox).

Comment: Understandable. Maybe it is because of the difference in counts for each gender? 16% of the entire dataset is women. Would this affect the overall average and not the category level one?

Comment: @StephanKolassa

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what is at play in Simpson's paradox. Take a look at the examples in the Wikipedia page and see whether something similar is happening in your dataset.